# Store generated dynamic unique ID and parse to next test case

Tags: rest, api, katalon-studio

I have keyword groovy which allowed me to generate a dynamic unique ID for test data purpose.

```html
package kw
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword


class dynamicId {

 //TIME STAMP
 String timeStamp() {
  return new SimpleDateFormat('ddMMyyyyhhmmss').format(new Date())
 }

 //Generate Random Number
 Integer getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
  return ((Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1))) as int) + min
 }

 /**
  * Generate a unique key and return value to service
  */
 @Keyword
 String getUniqueId() {
  String prodName = (Integer.toString(getRandomNumber(1, 99))) + timeStamp()

  return prodName
 }
}
```

Then I have a couple of API test cases as below:

test case 1:

POST test data by calling the keyword. this test case works well.

the dynamic unique ID is being posted and stored in the Database.

```html
partial test case


//test data using dynamic Id
NewId = CustomKeywords.'kw.dynamicId.getUniqueId'()
println('....DO' + NewId)

GlobalVariable.DynamicId = NewId

//test data to simulate Ingest Service sends Dispense Order to Dispense Order Service.
def incomingDOInfo = '{"Operation":"Add","Msg":{"id":"'+GlobalVariable.DynamicId+'"}'
```

now, test case 2 served as a verification test case.

where I need to verify the dynamic unique ID can be retrieved by GET API (GET back data by ID, this ID should matched the one being POSTED).

how do I store the generated dynamic unique ID once generated from test case 1?

i have the "println('....DO' + NewId)" in Test Case 1, but i have no idea how to use it and put it in test case 2.

which method should I use to get back the generated dynamic unique ID?

updated Test Case 2 with the suggestion, it works well.

```html
def dispenseOrderId = GlobalVariable.DynamicId
'Check data'
getDispenseOrder(dispenseOrderId)



def getDispenseOrder(def dispenseOrderId){
 def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject('Object Repository/Web Service Request/ApiDispenseorderByDispenseOrderIdGet', [('dispenseOrderId') : dispenseOrderId, ('SiteHostName') : GlobalVariable.SiteHostName, , ('SitePort') : GlobalVariable.SitePort]))
 println(response.statusCode)
 println(response.responseText)
 WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(response, 200)
 
 println(response.responseText)
 
 //convert to json format and verify result
 def dojson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new String(response.responseText))
 println('response text: \n' + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(dojson)))
 
 assertThat(dojson.dispenseOrderId).isEqualTo(dispenseOrderId)
 assertThat(dojson.state).isEqualTo("NEW")
}
```

====================

updated post to try #2 suggestion, works

TC2

```html
//retrieve the dynamic ID generated at previous test case
def file = new File("C:/DynamicId.txt")


//Modify this to match test data at test case "IncomingDOFromIngest"
def dispenseOrderId = file.text
'Check posted DO data from DO service'
getDispenseOrder(dispenseOrderId)



def getDispenseOrder(def dispenseOrderId){
 def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject('Object Repository/Web Service Request/ApiDispenseorderByDispenseOrderIdGet', [('dispenseOrderId') : dispenseOrderId, ('SiteHostName') : GlobalVariable.SiteHostName, , ('SitePort') : GlobalVariable.SitePort]))
 println(response.statusCode)
 println(response.responseText)
 WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(response, 200)
 
 println(response.responseText)
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing that that I can think of.

**1. Store the value od dynamic ID in a GlobalVariable**

If you are running Test Case 1 (TC1) and TC2 in a test suite, you can use the global variable for inter-storage.

You are already doing this in the TC1:

```
GlobalVariable.DynamicId = NewId
```

Now, this will **only** work if TC1 and TC2 are running as a part of **the same test suite.** That is because GlobalVariables are [reset to default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427982/katalon-when-is-a-globalvariable-reset) on the teardown of the test suite or the teardown of a test case when a single test case is run.

Let us say you retrieved the GET response and put it in a `response` variable.

```
assert response.equals(GlobalVariable.DynamicId)
```

**2. Store the value od dynamic ID on the filesystem**

This method will work even if you run the test cases separately (i.e. not in a test suite).

You can use file system for permanently storing the ID value to a file. There are various [Groovy mehods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_file_io.htm) to help you with that.

Here's an example on how to store the ID to a text file `c:/path-to/variable.txt`:

```
def file = new File("c:/path-to/variable.txt")
file.newWriter().withWriter { it << NewID }
println file.text
```

The TC2 needs this assertion (adjust according to your needs):

```
def file = new File("c:/path-to/variable.txt")
assert response.equals(file.text)
```

Make sure you defined `file` in TC2, as well.

**3. Return the ID value at the end of TC1 and use it as an input to TC2**

This also presupposes TC1 and TC2 are in the same test suite. You return the value of the ID with

```
return NewId
```

and then use as an input parameter for TC2.

**4. Use test listeners**

This is the same thing as the first solution, you just use test listeners to create a temporary holding variable that will be active during the test suite run.

Comment: suggestion 1 works. thanks. can i know more details about storing it permanently? or how about katalon test listener? as i afraid that tester might run test cases without the test suite and report failed case.

Comment: I will try to expand on #2 and #4 later in the day.

Comment: @user12158726 I added an explanation on #2.

Comment: i understand that Katalon has the function /DataFiles . can i use that path ? to store the file variable.txt? @Mate Mrše

Comment: You read the contents of a file with `file.text`. You forgot the `.text` part. Data files is not meant for this kind of stuff. You would usually use it for external data tables and such.

Comment: one more question, how do i bind the local file path to Katalon path, so the git repo or docker should work?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010304/how-to-get-test-case-name-in-katalon-studio) on RunConfigurations class, it that is what you need. You might try `RunConfiguration.getProjectDir()`. Or use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.